# How to pass in Collection of Guids Webapi + Restsharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I keep getting an error when I send in a collection of Guids

```
The value 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]' is not valid for Guid.
```

I think it is because restsharp is not handling the collection and basically just turning it into a string.

```
   var ids = checkedItems.Select(x => x.Items).ToList();

            var request = new RestRequest("default/Delete", Method.DELETE);

            for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count(); i++)
            {
                request.AddParameter("Ids" + i, ids[i]);
            }
```

this result in no binding

```
 var ids = checkedItems.Select(x => x.Items);
```

var request = new RestRequest("default/Delete", Method.DELETE);
    request.AddParameter("ids", ids);

Results in the "not valid guid" error.

```
           [HttpDelete]
   public HttpResponseMessage Delete([FromUri]DeleteVm vm)
    {
    }



public class DeleteVm 
{
    public IEnumerable<Guid> Ids { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i suspect `checkedItems.Select(x => x.Items).ToList()` is a list of lists of guids instead of the expected list of guids ... maybe you are looking for SelectMany() instead?

Comment: Oops, Actually it really is x.ItemIds sorry for name confusion, It is a list of Guids

Comment: the error says that the system expected a single guid where a list was passed (and thus, incorrectly was turned into a string by ToString() and cannot be converted back since the string does only contain the class name, not the guids) ... i think you need to pass single guids ... not lists of guids ...

Comment: Ya that is not an option, I could have 1 id and or 100 Guids to send in for deletion, it would be stupid to have to do 100 requests to achieve that.